# ServiceStack Not Caching Json

Tags: servicestack

I'm using ServiceStack on ASP.NET 4.5. I'm having troubles with the ServiceStack InMemory caching. If I just call the URL directly from the browser it pulls back the cached version, but if I try to call it via getJSON in JQuery, it never pulls back the cached version and just refetches the data each time.

Here's the basic code bits...

```
    public class AResponse : IHasResponseStatus
{
    public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }

    public Html Html { get; set; }
}   

public object Get(A request)
    {
        var cacheKey = UrnId.Create<string>(request.UserKey + request.Id);
        var expireInTimespan = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0);
        return RequestContext.ToOptimizedResultUsingCache(base.Cache, cacheKey, expireInTimespan, () =>
        {
            var ar = new AResponse();
            var html = new Html();
            html.Test = "test";
            ar.Html = html;
            return ar;
        });
    }
```

...Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: As I mentioned below...
Found the problem - I was passing callback=?, so jquery dynamically created the callback var - so the url was different each time on the getJSON call.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that when you call the Service from the browser you are going to cache a Html version. So, ServiceStack will insert/retrieve by applying a .html suffix onto your key. When you call it from JQuery it will cache a Json version and apply a .json suffix onto your key. You could test this by calling into your Service from the browser using `?format=json` on the url. This would cache a json version (instead of html) and then calling from JQuery to get the cached json.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But - even if I just always call directly from the jquery getJSON and never directly via the browser, it still will not cache.
Now, if I call via browser and add ?format=json it will cache. So, it only seems it will not cache if called via jquery getJSON - which  is of course the one I want to cache.

Comment: You can try adding the '?format=json' to the url in your jquery getJSON call.

Comment: Found the problem - I was passing callback=?, so jquery dynamically created the callback var - so the url was different each time on the getJSON call. :-) Thanks for the reply.